# AsyncHttpResponseHandler getting undefined for send params ;RequestParams, android, java, php

Tags: java, php, android, post, android-asynctask

I have this code to upload data to database

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
//prgDialog.show();
params.put("usersJSON", controller.getAllAnswerSheet());
System.out.println("onSuccess getAllAnswerSheet" + controller.numberOfRows("answer_sheet_tbl"));
System.out.println("onSuccess getAllAnswerSheet" + controller.getAllAnswerSheet());
// Make Http call to updatesyncsts.php with JSON parameter which has Sync statuses of Users
client.post("http://127.0.0.1/qna/process/uploadanswersheet.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

I know i have data because i get this in log

```
[{
    "answer": [{
        "sysid": "1",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "1",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "2",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "2",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "3",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "3",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "4",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "4",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "5",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "5",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "6",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "6",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "7",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "0",
        "answerid": "",
        "householdid": "7",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "8",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "1",
        "answerid": "aklan",
        "householdid": "8",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "9",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "2",
        "answerid": "kalibo",
        "householdid": "9",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "10",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "3",
        "answerid": "7",
        "householdid": "10",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "11",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "3",
        "answerid": "7",
        "householdid": "11",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "12",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "3",
        "answerid": "7",
        "householdid": "12",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "13",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "6",
        "answerid": "three",
        "householdid": "13",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "14",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "6",
        "answerid": "three",
        "householdid": "14",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "15",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "7",
        "answerid": "patwo",
        "householdid": "15",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "16",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "7",
        "answerid": "pathree",
        "householdid": "16",
        "status": "active"
    }, {
        "sysid": "17",
        "surveyid": "1",
        "questionid": "7",
        "answerid": "pathree",
        "householdid": "17",
        "status": "active"
    }],
    "survey": [{
        "sysid": "17",
        "householdnum": "74",
        "barangay": "manila",
        "headfname": "martin",
        "headmname": "",
        "headlname": "manalo",
        "headsuffix": "",
        "status": "active"
    }]
}]
```

My problem is in my `uploadanswersheet.php` page I get `Undefined index: usersJSON` Meaning I was not able to send the the data in params.

This is my code in `uploadanswersheet.php`:

```
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"];
//Remove Slashes
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($json), true);
//if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
//$json = stripslashes($json);
//}
```

Comment: please check if usersJSON is being posted to php by using isset if(isset($_POST['usersJSON'])) {
    echo "true";
}else{ echo "false"; }

Comment: *"AsyncHttpResponseHandler getting undefined for send params RequestParams android java php"*  - Is that a sentence?  Or just a collection of words?

Comment: @JagadeshaNH it is not being posted because the error says undefined. i just tried sending a text and the php gets it. Is not allow to send JSONArray in params?Do i have to convert it to string then convert it again in php?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival yes you need to convert it to string, why don't you use, Apache HTTP Client.

Comment: because this way was the first one i encounter when searching for solution i will try the Apache HTTP when i converted it to string it worked you can provide that as an answer and i will accept it asap @JagadeshaNH

Comment: checkout retrofit it's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert JSON to string and post it. And at server side convert back string to JSON